# Get time complexity of the recursion: T(n)=4T(n-1) - 3T(n-2)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

I  have a recurrence relation given by:

```
T(n)=4T(n-1) - 3T(n-2)
```

How do I solve this?
Any detailed explanation:

What I tried was that I substituted for `T(n-1)` on the right hand side using the relation and I got this:

```
 =16T(n-2)-12T(n-3)-3T(n-2)
```

But I don't know where and how to end this.

Answer (score 3):

Not only you can easily get the time complexity of this recursion, but you can even solve it exactly. This is thanks to the exhaustive theory behind linear recurrence relations and the one you called here is a specific case of [homogeneous linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

To solve it you need to write a characteristic polynomial: `t^2 -4t +3` and find it's roots which are `t=1` and `t=3`. Which means that your solution is of the form:

`T(n) = c1 + 3^n * c2`.

You can get `c1` and `c2` if you have a boundary conditions, but for your case it is enough to claim `O(3^n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Trying T(n) = x^n gives you a quadratic equation: x^2 = 4x - 3. This has solutions x=1 and x=3, so the general form for T(n) is a + b*3^n. The exact values of a and b depend on the initial conditions (for example, the values of T(0) and T(1)).

Depending on the initial conditions, the solution is going to be O(1) or O(3^n).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE :-** Generally, these kind of recurrence relations (where number of recurrence function calls are repeated , e.g-`recurrence relation for a fibonacci sequence for value n` ) will result into an exponential time complexity.

First of all, your question is incomplete . It does not provide a termination condition ( a condition for which the recurrence will terminate ). I assume that it must be

> T(n) = 1 for n=1 and 2 for n=2

Based on this assumption I start breaking down the above recurrence relation

On substituting T(n) into T(n-1) I get this :

`16T(n-2) - 24T(n-3) + 9T(n-4)`

this forms a polynomial in the power of 2

```
{(4^2)T(n-2) - 2.4.3 T(n-3) + (3^2) T(n-4)}
```

again breaking the above recurrence further we get :

`64T(n-3) -144T(n-4) + 108T(n-5) -27T(n-6)`

which is a polynomial of power 3

on breaking down the relation for n-1 terms we will get :

`(4^n-1) T(1) - .............` something like that

we can clearly see that in the above expansion all the remaining terms will be less than 4^n-1 so, we can take the asymptotic notation as :

`O(4^n)`

As an exercise you can either expand the polynomial for few more terms and also draw the recursion tree to find out what's actually happening .

Answer (score 1):

While it's obviously `O(4^n)` (because `T(n)<=4*T(n-1)`), it looks like a smaller limit can be proved:

`T(n) = 4*T(n-1) - 3*T(n-2)`

`T(n) - T(n-1) = 3*T(n-1) - 3*T(n-2)`

`D(n) = T(n) - T(n-1)`

`D(n) = 3*D(n-1)`

`D(n) = D(0) * 3^n`

if `D(0)=0`, `T(n)=const=O(1)`

otherwise since the difference is exponential, the resulting function will be exponential as well:

`T(n) = O(3^n)`